# No result from Substring

Tags: powershell

Hey guys i´m just starting with powershell, now I´ve got this problem. I try to check wheater the last character of a inputed path is a "\". But when I run this code the variable $lastRootPathChar is empty. The $end and $start variables get the integers I want them to have, but the .Substring seems to return nothing. What am I doing wrong?

```
    $RootPath = Read-Host 'Please enter the rootpath: '
    $start = $RootPath.Length-1
    $end = $RootPath.Length
    $lastRootPathChar = $RootPath.Substring($start,$end)
    if($lastRootPathChar -ne "\")
    {
        $RootPath = $RootPath + "\"
    }
```

Comment: Please paste *code* into the question, not a *screenshot* of code

Comment: For future reference, paste your code in a question, not a screenshot of your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two parameters passed to that overload of  [`String.Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) are start and ***length*** not start and *end*

```
$lastRootPathChar = $RootPath.Substring($start,1)
```

Comment: Thank you also. Is that semicolon needed?

Comment: @user5883013 - no, force of habit writing c#.

Comment: @Jamiec - Just was wondering because I do that mistake a lot of times a day. I also writing most time c#.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to `"".Substring()` is the *total length* of the desired substring, not the end index.

```
$LastChar = $RootPath.Substring($start, 1)
```

You could also use the index operator `[]` to access the *last* `char` in the string (index `-1`):

```
$LastChar = $RootPath[-1] -as [string]
```

Comment: Looks like were thinking alike today!

Answer (score 0):

$lastRootPathChar = $RootPath.Substring($RootPath.length -1)

This will get the slash out. As $RootPath.length -1 is the index of the last character and there are no characters after that.